# How to show a Content Dialog with multiple input fields from viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, dialog, uwp-xaml

I am building an **C# UWP** application where onclick of a button in the view a command (using System.Windows.Input.IComand) raises in **viewmodel**(not code behind) which builds a form of input fields like `Name:____` `phone:____` etc and shows it on the UI/view.

- I dont want to keep the `<ContentDialog></ContentDialog>` in the
  view.

***What have I done so far is***

**Button in my view:**

```xml
<CommandBar>
 <AppBarButton x:Name="buttonNew" Command="{Binding AddClick}" />
</CommandBar>
```

- ViewModel object in the code behind is set as the DataContext of the
  View

**In the view model:**

```cs
public ICommand AddClick=> new RelayCommand(Add);

private async void Add()
{
    TextBox input = new TextBox()
    {
        PlaceholderText = "Name",
    };

    var contentDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "Add a Person",
        Content = input,                    
        FullSizeDesired = true,
        PrimaryButtonText = "Add",
        CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
    };
    await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

As you can see I am able to show/trigger a Content Dialog box with one input field and 2 buttons.

***My problem is:***

1. How to add more input fields like we add in a
   `<StackPanel></StackPanel>` in the code of view model and assign it
   to the content of the Content Dialog?
2. How to size it accordingly that all the fields show up properly and does not show up haphazard since am not coding this in the Xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the general application construction practice, it is recommended to create a UI using XAML to create a custom `ContentDialog`.

You don’t have to write the XAML code of `ContentDialog` in the View, you can add new item in Visual Studio, select the Content Dialog template, and create a custom dialog derived from `ContentDialog`.

Then use code similar to the following:

**MyCustomDialog.xaml**

```xml
<ContentDialog
    ...
    Title="Add a Person"
    FullSizeDesired="True"
    PrimaryButtonText="Add"
    CloseButtonText="Cancel"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick">

    <StackPanel>
        
        <TextBox Header="Name" x:Name="NameBox" PlaceholderText="Name"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        
        <TextBox Header="Phone" x:Name="PhoneBox" PlaceholderText="Phone"
                 Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 InputScope="Number"/>
        
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
private async void Add()
{
    var dialog = new MyCustomDialog();
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

---

If you insist on using C# code to create `ContentDialog`, you need to convert the tags in XAML into corresponding classes, but this method is not easy to debug.

```cs
private async void Add()
{
    var container = new StackPanel();

    TextBox nameBox = new TextBox()
    {
        PlaceholderText = "Name",
        Header = "Name",
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
    };

    TextBox phoneBox = new TextBox()
    {
        PlaceholderText = "Phone",
        Header = "Phone",
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0)
    };

    container.Children.Add(nameBox);
    container.Children.Add(phoneBox);

    var contentDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "Add a Person",
        Content = container,
        FullSizeDesired = true,
        PrimaryButtonText = "Add",
        CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
    };
    await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

The tags in XAML are actually the corresponding classes in C#, from the code you provided, the `ContentDialog` is displayed in full screen. You mentioned that you want the fields to be displayed correctly, if you mean that the string entered in the `TextBox` is too long and the text is not displayed completely, you can set the `TextBox.TextWrapping` property to **True**.

Comment: It works! thanks for the insight about the general application construction practice. it really helps. I made it in xaml now. It works fine, but when the dialog box appears on the screen, for the first 1-2 secs it expands and then contracts according to the size of it's contents. why so? is it normal or some coding fault?